# How do I undo a previous commit in Github

Tags: git, github, git-revert

So I've been working on this PR and it turns out that I need to revert a certain commit/push, note that I created multiple commits and pushes after that commit but I want everything to remain the same and only that commit to revert back, is that possible and how?

Answer (score 5):

you can use

```
git revert <commitID>
```

This effectively create a new commit that reverse the previous commit.

Remember to commit/push after that.

Answer (score 0):

to see the history of commit and their hash value

```
git log
```

to undo a commit (soft reset)

```
git reset hash-value
```

if you want to erase the file and other changes after that commit then do a hard reset.

once you undo your commit you can push your changes to your Github!

```
git reset --hard hash-value
```

Comment: `once you undo your commit you can push your changes to your Github!` - OR not :) because the working copy would be behind the remote, so you'd need to either pull (which would recreate the removed commit) or force push (don't do this without knowing what you're doing). In the absence of any reason to act differently, a commit should always be undone via `revert`.

Comment: point understood thanks :)

Comment: please edit it as you like :) @AD7six

Comment: I think this question has been answered enough times already :)